# Combobox selection enabling another combobox

Tags: wpf-controls, wcf-binding

I was wondering if there is anyway to set a binding to enable a combobox if a parent combobox has any selection in it.

For instance, I have three comboboxes, Job, Type and Task.  You should only be able to select them in that order.

I know I could do it easily with code behind but if there is a way to do binding I think I'd like to do that instead.